# "Related Tags" label is inaccurate when viewing "All Questions"

Tags: bug, tags, user-interface, related-tags

When browsing the [**All Questions**](https://superuser.com/questions) section on Super User, I noticed that the sidebar included a **Related Tags** section. Since there wasn't any specific tag being searched, the section simply lists the 10 most popular tags on the site.

[image: Related tags listed by popularity]

This seems to happen on all SE sited I've tested, including [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions), [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions), and [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions).

It's by no means a major issue, but shouldn't the phrase "Popular Tags" be used instead?

Comment: Well, there is a high chance in seeing these tags when browsing all question, so they are some kind of related :D.